# How does one interact with Chromium-based browsers' GPU process programmatically (PowerShell?, JavaScript?), to detect absurd memory footprint / leak?

Tags: javascript, powershell, gpu, chromium

I was hoping to set up some sort of script (preferably) or small program that would detect and automatically end/restart Chromium's GPU process when it exceeds a certain memory threshold.

Turning off hardware acceleration prevents the bloating of course, but I was interested in a way to use the feature while keeping it in check, without having to launch the Task Manager > End Process every hour or so.

Comment: This is a much better question than [the previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58785268/1048572), asking for help with your specific use case :-)

Comment: I appreciate your assistance / guidance, Bergi.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the question, but it's the top Google search hit combining "chrome" "gpu process" and "script". There don't seem to be any answers out there, so here's mine.

At least on Windows, it looks as if every chromium-based product with GPU-assisted rendering spins up a process with `--gpu-process` in the command-line. This applies to any Electron apps as well, as I see this on my main PC for apps like Slack, Discord and Skype, as well as other downstream Chromium-based browsers. The actual process name will match the product's main image name, so you can differentiate that way.

This should allow one to use any program language that can inspect the command line of running process, find their PID, and monitor the process's memory usage, killing it when it's over some threshold. Search for the expected image name (such as `chrome.exe`) and check for `--gpu-process` in the arguments or full command-line.

When you terminate it, it will be automatically restarted ... as long as you don't kill it too often. The chromium code includes a check meant to protect against the gpu-render process "flapping" up and down when it *actually* crashes. It unlikely to know the difference in an external tool killing the gpu render process and the process crashing due to some issue. Based on what I'm seeing, I believe the control process will stop restarting the gpu-render process if it dies more than once an hour.